# Why await doesn't wait asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm writing a coroutine to execute shell command in python base on a tutorial. Here are basic:

```
import asyncio

async def async_procedure():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('ping', '-c', '2', 'google.com')
    await process.wait()
    print('async procedure done.')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(async_procedure())
loop.close()
```

This code above work perfectly. It gives a result like that:

```
PING google.com (...) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ...: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=34.8 ms
64 bytes from ...: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=34.5 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.771/34.437/34.881/0.407 ms
Process done!
```

When I try remove process.wait():

```
async def async_procedure():
    await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('ping', '-c', '2', 'google.com')
    print('async procedure done.')
```

The script doesn't work as expected:

```
Process done! # This line should be lastest line
PING google.com (...) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ...: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=21.1 ms
64 bytes from ...: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=21.8 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.135/21.469/21.803/0.334 ms
```

But there is no problem in a very similar example:

```
async def async_procedure():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('async procedure done')
```

- So why await doesn't wait asyncio.create_subprocess_exec() ?

The docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine) says:

> result = await future or result = yield from future – **suspends** the coroutine until the future is done, then returns the future’s result, or raises an exception, which will be propagated. (If the future is cancelled, it will raise a CancelledError exception.) Note that tasks are futures, and everything said about futures also applies to tasks.
>
> result = await coroutine or result = yield from coroutine – **wait** for another coroutine to produce a result (or raise an exception, which will be propagated). The coroutine expression must be a call to another coroutine.
>
> return expression – produce a result to the coroutine that is waiting for this one using await or yield from.
>
> raise exception – raise an exception in the coroutine that is waiting for this one using await or yield from.

- What is actually process's flow when coroutine **suspending** and **waiting** ?

Here are source code of asyncio.create_subprocess_exec() and asyncio.sleep() are coroutine. Both of them are coroutines:

```
@coroutine
def create_subprocess_exec(program, *args, stdin=None, stdout=None,
                           stderr=None, loop=None,
                           limit=streams._DEFAULT_LIMIT, **kwds):
    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_event_loop()
    protocol_factory = lambda: SubprocessStreamProtocol(limit=limit,
                                                        loop=loop)
    transport, protocol = yield from loop.subprocess_exec(
                                            protocol_factory,
                                            program, *args,
                                            stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout,
                                            stderr=stderr, **kwds)
    return Process(transport, protocol, loop)


@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay == 0:
        yield
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    h = future._loop.call_later(delay,
                                futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                                future, result)
    try:
        return (yield from future)
    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You waited for the process to start. You did not wait for it to finish. `await process.wait()` waits for it to finish.

Comment: I can't believe this problem is so simple. Thank you @user2357112!